Matrices respecting the quaternionic inner product are symplectic and unitary
I am trying to prove that the group of matrices respecting the inner product in $\mathbb{H}^n$ can be realized as the symplectic unitary matrices $\text{Sp}(2n, \mathbb{C}) \cap \text{U}(2n, \mathbb{C})$ that preserve both a Hermitian form and a skew-symmetric form, using the representation of quaternions as pairs of complex numbers. I have a proof of this fact, but the Hermitian and skew-symmetric forms that are being preserved are not exactly what I expected them to be, and I'd like to see if there's a meaningful explanation of this.
When representing quaternions as pairs of complex numbers $q = a + bi + cj + dk = (a+bi) + (c+di)j = \alpha + \beta j$, quaternionic conjugation becomes $q^{*} = a - bi - cj - dk =\overline{\alpha} - \beta j$ and multiplication on the left by $j$ becomes $j\alpha = \overline{\alpha}j$, where the bar represents complex conjugation. Additionally, $j^2 = -1$.
Therefore we can write the quaternionic inner product as:
\begin{align}
q_1^{*}q_2 
&= (\overline{\alpha_1} - \beta_1 j)(\alpha_2 + \beta_2 j) \\
&= \overline{\alpha_1}\alpha_2  +  \overline{\alpha_1}\beta_2 j - \beta_1 j \alpha_2  - \beta_1 j \beta_2 j \\
&= (\overline{\alpha_1} \alpha_2 +\beta_1 \overline{\beta_2}) + (\overline{\alpha_1}\beta_2 - \overline{\alpha_2} \beta_1)j.
\end{align}
If we define the expressions $f(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2) = \overline{\alpha_1} \alpha_2 +\beta_1 \overline{\beta_2}$ and $g(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2) = \overline{\alpha_1}\beta_2 - \overline{\alpha_2} \beta_1$, then $f$ is conjugate-symmetric and $g$ is skew-symmetric because $f(\alpha_2, \beta_2, \alpha_1, \beta_1) = \overline{f(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2)}$ and $g(\alpha_2, \beta_2, \alpha_1, \beta_1) = - g(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2)$.
However, the forms $f$ and $g$ do not quite satisfy the linearity properties that Hermitian forms and skew-symmetric forms should satisfy. For instance, $f(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \lambda \alpha_2, \lambda \beta_2) \neq \lambda f(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2)$.
It is possible to fix this proof by defining new forms $F(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2) = f(\overline{\alpha_1}, \beta_1, \overline{\alpha_2}, \beta_2)$ and $G(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \alpha_2, \beta_2) = g(\overline{\alpha_1}, \beta_1, \overline{\alpha_2}, \beta_2)$, which will have the appropriate linearity. Therefore preserving the quaternionic inner product is equivalent to preserving $F$ and $G$, which are preserved by unitary and symplectic matrices.
However, I'm not satisfied that I understand the reason this fix is needed. Is there a way I could have realized in advance that I need to take conjugates of $\alpha$ to make these forms linear? Why should $F$ and $G$ be preferred to $f$ and $g$?

Well multiplication is not commutative, so if you want left-multiplicativity, you don't want $\lambda$'s appearing in the middle of products.

Makes sense, using the representation $q = \alpha + j \beta$ gives the linear forms directly. There's probably not a better explanation than the fact that one of the representations has to be linear on the conjugate and the other will be directly linear because of the lack of commutativity $j\alpha = \overline{\alpha}j$.

As mentioned by Kimball in the comments, the lack of commutativity of multiplication means multiplying on the wrong side will introduce a conjugation.
